# Add text compression to Swashbuckle API

Tags: c#, asp.net, swashbuckle

I am developing an ASP.NET application, hosted by IIS. I have activated IIS text compression, so all the pages served are automatically GZipped (if client requesting them support that).

Unfortunately i don't find a way to tell Swashbuckle to apply compression to API responses, so that produced API responses are somewhat compressed.

Is it a feature supported by the tool? if so how should I proceede to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem adding this nuget package :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server/2.0.6?_src=template

And this two line of code in application start :

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(contentSizeThreshold : 8192, new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```